# DataGridView with limited number of rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to have a datagridview with limited number of rows. The user can add rows by directly typing in the cell and also by using a button. I have gone through similar questions on internet and used the code there but it doesn't work properly.

Currently in the code I am posting, it works correctly until I start typing in the last row and then I get stack overflow exception.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    int maxNumberOfRows = 6;

    private void dgv1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckRowCount();
    }

    private void dgv1_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckRowCount();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgv1.Rows.Count < maxNumberOfRows)
            dgv1.Rows.Add("Row added by button");
        else
            dgv1.Rows[dgv1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = "Row added by button";
    }

    private void CheckRowCount()
    {
        if (dgv1.Rows.Count <= maxNumberOfRows)
            dgv1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        else
            dgv1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using an internal object that is assigned to the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridVies`? This way you can control the list and the amount of items in the list in order to maintain a maximum amount of items (in the list, and therefor the amount of rows in the dgv)

Comment: Row and column indexes are zero index, so the first 6 rows are indexed 0,1,2,3,4 and 5. Using "if (dgv1.Rows.Count <= maxNumberOfRows)" will allow a seventh row that uses an index of 6. Get rid of the equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

Change if (dgv1.Rows.Count <= maxNumberOfRows) to if (dgv1.Rows.Count < maxNumberOfRows)

Remove the = character.